# get the current location fast and once in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I have an android application that need device current location (latitude and longitude). I've tried some tutorial on the net and specially some solutions from stack overflow, but they doesn't work well for me. My requirement is so simple: First I need it to be fast and need the location once when I the fragment starts. Second I need it to be as precise as possible, I mean it should use GPS first if GPS is not available then use Network provider.

For example, I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a) but it return null after 30 second, but I know there is some all the things is ok because google map and other application works well !!!

Something that almost all the answers suggest is to use getLastKnownLocation(), but I suppose it's not the current and I don't want it if it is so.

can anyone suggest me some kind of simple and fast way to get the location just ONCE ?!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348535/6667442

Comment: Within the same above thread, there is an example using a LocationProvider Class that provides flexibility for one to infinite location updates.

Comment: Please see the below link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68096652/4042384](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68096652/4042384) hope it will help you

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Here, you can use this...

Example usage:

```
public void foo(Context context) {
  // when you need location
  // if inside activity context = this;

  SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(context, 
   new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
     @Override public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location) {
       Log.d("Location", "my location is " + location.toString());
     }
   });
}
```

You might want to verify the lat/long are actual values and not 0 or something. If I remember correctly this shouldn't throw an NPE but you might want to verify that.

```
public class SingleShotLocationProvider {

  public static interface LocationCallback {
      public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location);
  }

  // calls back to calling thread, note this is for low grain: if you want higher precision, swap the 
  // contents of the else and if. Also be sure to check gps permission/settings are allowed.
  // call usually takes <10ms
  public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {
      final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
      boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
      if (isNetworkEnabled) {
          Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
          criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
          locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
              @Override
              public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                  callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
              }

              @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
              @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
              @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
          }, null);
      } else {
          boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
          if (isGPSEnabled) {
              Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
              criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
              locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                      callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                  }

                  @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
                  @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
                  @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
              }, null);
          }
      }
  }


  // consider returning Location instead of this dummy wrapper class
  public static class GPSCoordinates {
      public float longitude = -1;
      public float latitude = -1;

      public GPSCoordinates(float theLatitude, float theLongitude) {
          longitude = theLongitude;
          latitude = theLatitude;
      }

      public GPSCoordinates(double theLatitude, double theLongitude) {
          longitude = (float) theLongitude;
          latitude = (float) theLatitude;
      }
  }  
}
```

Comment: To improve the SingleShotLocationProvider, either add permission check at runtime or make the method handle a possible SecurityException

Comment: thank you, it works in android 5 and lower. but i can't run it on android 7.

Comment: Is this still the best/recommended way in 2019?

Answer (score 8):

For anyone interested in retrieving a single location update, in the best, idiomatic way, using the latest APIs, and the magic of Kotlin, here you go:

Gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0"
    ...
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <!-- required only for LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
    <!-- required for all other priorities -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Somewhere in your `Extensions` file:

```
// To use PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, you must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
// Any other priority will require just ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
// but will not guarantee a location update
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
suspend fun FusedLocationProviderClient.awaitCurrentLocation(priority: Int): Location? {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine {
        // to use for request cancellation upon coroutine cancellation
        val cts = CancellationTokenSource()
        getCurrentLocation(priority, cts.token)
            .addOnSuccessListener {location ->
                // remember location is nullable, this happens sometimes
                // when the request expires before an update is acquired
                it.resume(location)
            }.addOnFailureListener {e ->
                it.resumeWithException(e)
            }

        it.invokeOnCancellation {
            cts.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

In your fragment:

```
// need to register this anywhere before onCreateView, idealy as a field
private val permissionRequester = registerForActivityResult(
    // you can use RequestPermission() contract if you only need 1 permission
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
) { map ->
    // If you requested 1 permission, change `map` to `isGranted`
    // Keys are permissions Strings, values are isGranted Booleans
    // An easy way to check if "any" permission was granted is map.containsValue(true)
    // You can use your own logic for multiple permissions, 
    // but they have to follow the same checks here:
    val response = map.entries.first()
    val permission = response.key
    val isGranted = response.value
    when {
        isGranted -> onPermissionGranted()
        ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(requireContext(), permission) -> {
            // permission denied but not permanently, tell user why you need it. 
            // Idealy provide a button to request it again and another to dismiss
            AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
                .setTitle(R.string.perm_request_rationale_title)
                .setMessage(R.string.perm_request_rationale)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.request_perm_again) { _, _ -> 
                     requirePermission() 
                }
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.dismiss, null)
                .create()
                .show()
        } 
        else -> {
            // permission permanently denied
            // 1) tell user the app won't work as expected, or
            // 2) take him to your app's info screen to manually change permissions, or
            // 3) silently and gracefully degrade user experience
            // I'll leave the implementation to you
        }
    }
}
```

onPermissionGranted function:

```
private fun onPermissionGranted() {
    val lm = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    if(LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(lm)) {
        // you can do this your own way, eg. from a viewModel
        // but here is where you wanna start the coroutine.
        // Choose your priority based on the permission you required
        val priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val location = LocationServices
                .getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
                .awaitCurrentLocation(priority)
            // do whatever with this location, notice that it's nullable
        }
    } else {
        // prompt user to enable location or launch location settings check
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is add this to MyLocation button click listener:

```
private fun requirePermission() {
    val permissions = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        // optional: Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    )
    permissionRequester.launch(permissions)
}
```

Note that this has the beauty of checking if the permission was already given implicitly, and not show a dialog/request if that was the case.
Ergo, always start your flow by launching the requester and only do your checks in its callback.

Answer (score 5):

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location onlyOneLocation;
    private final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1234;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    @Override public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        onlyOneLocation = location;
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
    @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
    @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("gps", "Location permission granted");
                try {
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, this);
                }
                catch (SecurityException ex) {
                    Log.d("gps", "Location permission did not work!");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay it compiles, but not sure where location is stored

Comment: onlyOneLocation.getLatituide(); onlyOneLocation.getLongitude();

Comment: add a null check to  onlyOneLocation = location;
 other wise the location could be set null then never update...

Answer (score 5):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
> ```
>
> [Requesting User Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

---

**build.gradle** (Module: app)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    ...
}
```

> If you receive an error, check that your top-level build.gradle
>   contains a reference to the google() repo or to maven { url
>   "https://maven.google.com" }

[Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

---

**LocationService.kt**

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Looper
import android.provider.Settings
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.alert
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync
import org.jetbrains.anko.okButton

object LocationService {

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
    private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            doAsync {
                location = locationResult.lastLocation
                onSuccess(location)
            }
        }
    }
    private lateinit var onSuccess: (location : Location) -> Unit
    private lateinit var onError: () -> Unit
    lateinit var location: Location

    fun init(activity: Activity) {
        fusedLocationProviderClient = FusedLocationProviderClient(activity)
        locationRequest = LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(1000).setFastestInterval(1000).setNumUpdates(1)
    }

    private fun checkLocationStatusAndGetLocation(activity: Activity) {
        doAsync {
            when {
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity).checkLocationSettings(LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest).setAlwaysShow(true).build()).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    doAsync {
                        try {
                            task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
                        } catch (exception: ApiException) {
                            when (exception.statusCode) {
                                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                                    try {
                                        (exception as ResolvableApiException).startResolutionForResult(activity, 7025)
                                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                                        promptShowLocation(activity)
                                    }
                                }
                                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                                    promptShowLocation(activity)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) -> activity.runOnUiThread {
                    activity.alert("To continue, allow the device to use location, witch uses Google's Location Service") {
                        okButton {
                            val ite = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.fromParts("package", activity.packageName, null))
                            ite.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                            activity.startActivity(ite)
                            onError()
                        }
                        negativeButton("Cancelar", { onError() })
                        onCancelled { onError() }
                    }.show()
                }
                else -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 7024)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun promptShowLocation(activity: Activity) {
        activity.runOnUiThread {
            activity.alert("To continue, allow the device to use location, witch uses Google's Location Service") {
                okButton {
                    activity.startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
                    onError()
                }
                negativeButton("Cancelar", { onError() })
                onCancelled { onError() }
            }.show()
        }
    }

    fun onRequestPermissionsResult(activity: Activity, requestCode: Int, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == 7024) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                checkLocationStatusAndGetLocation(activity)
            } else {
                onError()
            }
        }
    }

    fun onActivityResult(activity: Activity, requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int) {
        if (requestCode == 7025) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                checkLocationStatusAndGetLocation(activity)
            } else {
                onError()
            }
        }
    }

    fun getLocation(activity: Activity, onSuccess: () -> Unit, onError: () -> Unit) {
        this.onSuccess = onSuccess
        this.onError = onError
        checkLocationStatusAndGetLocation(activity)
    }

}
```

---

**your activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    LocationService.init(this)
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    LocationService.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    LocationService.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode)
}

private fun yourFunction() {
    LocationService.getLocation(this, { location ->
        //TODO: use the location
    }, {
        //TODO: display error message
    })
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. It worked very well and before making api call, I was able to get lattitude and longitude. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is achieved using the [`LocationManager#requestSingleUpdate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). This method attaches a listener in a given looper (if you want or have it) and notifies the location ASAP it is received, only once. The method you suggest is used only as an inexact position before the real one is given to you.

In any case it will be fast than milliseconds (unless you are lucky enough to start listening when a location came to the device). Think on the GPS as an element that you enable when waiting for locations and disable when you remove this listening. This behavior is done to avoid draining the user's battery.

So, to sum up:

- The time between you start listening and you receive the position depends on the device's GPS (manufacture, location of the user, satellite coverage...)
- There is a method in the Android SDK to listen for a single update.
- By providing the a criteria object, you can manage which criterias are acceptable for you to receive a location. Stronger criterias means more time to get an accurate response.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Get LocationManager object
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    //latitude of location
    double myLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    //longitude og location
    double myLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Why the if statement is using '&&' and not '||' ? you need only one of the permissions to access location?

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are not worked for me so I answered this
Initially add the dependencies

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

after add the class MyLocationListiner.java

```
package com.example.firebase_auth;

/**
 * Created by Chromicle(Ajay Prabhakar).
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import static android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public static double latitude;
    Context ctx;
    Location location;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    public static double longitude;
    MyLocationListener(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "GPS Enable " + isGPSEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Network Enable " + isNetworkEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    ( ctx, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION )
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( ctx,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {  }
            if (isGPSEnabled == true) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,     0,       0, this);
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (isNetworkEnabled==true) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,    0,     0, this);
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            // Toast.makeText(ctx,"latitude: "+latitude+" longitude: "+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            Toast.makeText(ctx,"Exception "+ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        //print "Currently GPS is Disabled";
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        //print "GPS got Enabled";
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {

    }
}
```

To use that class add this method 
location is stored in the Address string

```
public void getLocation(){
        Double latitude = 0.0, longitude;
        String message = "";
        LocationManager mlocManager = null;
        LocationListener mlocListener;
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
        if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            latitude = MyLocationListener.latitude;
            longitude = MyLocationListener.longitude;
            message = message +"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/@"+ latitude +","+  longitude;
            address=message;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (latitude == 0.0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Currently gps has not found your location....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is currently off...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helpfull

Answer (score -1):

I have created some classes using those you can easily get the current location. I used FusedLocationProviderClient for getting the current location.

First Add this into your manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Then Check for location permission:

```
 private fun startCheckingLocation() {
    if (checkLocationPermissions() == true) {
        checkGPSEnabled()
    } else {
        askLocationPermission()
    }
}
```

checkLocationPermissions method:

```
 private fun checkLocationPermissions(): Boolean? {
    return PermissionUtils.hasPermissions(
        requireContext(),
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    )
}
```

checkGPSEnabled method:

```
 private fun checkGPSEnabled() {
    GpsUtils(requireContext()) {
        it?.let {
            startCheckingCurrentLocation()
        }
    }.apply {
        turnGPSOn(gpsDialogCallback)
    }
}
```

As OnActivityResult is Deprecated:

```
     private val gpsDialogCallback =     registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { activityResult ->
        activityResult?.let { result ->
            when (result.resultCode) {
                RESULT_OK -> {
                    startCheckingCurrentLocation()
                }
                RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

startCheckingCurrentLocation method :

```
 private fun startCheckingCurrentLocation() {
    LocationUtils(requireContext()) { location ->
        Log.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + location.latitude + " " + location.longitude)
        startIntentService(location)
    }.apply {
        startLocationUpdates()
    }
}
```

For GPS I have created one class that you can simply put and use it:

GPSUtils:

```
class GpsUtils(
private val context: Context,
private val gpsStatus: (isEnable: Boolean?) -> Unit
) {

private val mSettingsClient: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context)
private val mLocationSettingsRequest: LocationSettingsRequest
private val locationManager: LocationManager =
    context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
private val locationRequest: LocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()

init {
    locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    locationRequest.interval = 10 * 1000.toLong()
    locationRequest.fastestInterval = 2 * 1000.toLong()
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build()
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true) //this is the key ingredient
}

// method for turn on GPS
fun turnGPSOn(gpsDialogCallback: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>) {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        gpsStatus.invoke(true)
    } else {
        mSettingsClient
            .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                (context as Activity)
            ) {
                //  GPS is already enable, callback GPS status through listener
                gpsStatus.invoke(true)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(context) { e ->
                when ((e as ApiException).statusCode) {
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult() and check the result in onActivityResult().

                        if (e is ResolvableApiException) {
                            try {
                                val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(e.resolution).build()
                                gpsDialogCallback.launch(intentSenderRequest)
                            } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (sie: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                        Timber.i("PendingIntent unable to execute request.")
                    }
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        val errorMessage =
                            "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Fix in Settings."
                        Timber.e(errorMessage)
                    }
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.CANCELED -> {
                        val errorMessage =
                            "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Fix in Settings."
                        Timber.e(errorMessage)
                    }
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        val errorMessage =
                            "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Fix in Settings."
                        Timber.e(errorMessage)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

}
```

For checking location I have created one more class :

```
class LocationUtils(
context: Context,
private val latLng: (location: Location) -> Unit) {

private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient? = null

private val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()?.apply {
    interval = 20 * 1000.toLong()
    fastestInterval = 2 * 1000.toLong()
    priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
}


init {
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
}

/**
 * call when location permission is allowed and you want to fetch the last location of the user
 */
fun getLastLocation() {
    fusedLocationClient?.lastLocation?.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
        location?.let {
            latLng.invoke(location)
            stopLocationUpdates()
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Requested location callback
 */
private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {

        locationResult ?: return

        for (location in locationResult.locations) {
            location?.let {
                latLng.invoke(it)
                stopLocationUpdates()
            }
        }
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
    }
}

/**
 * call when location permission is already given to user and you want to receive continues location updates
 */
fun startLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(
        locationRequest,
        locationCallback,
        Looper.getMainLooper()
    )
}

/**
 * call when you want to stop location updates
 */
fun stopLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient?.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)?.addOnCompleteListener { }
}


}
```

I have created one worker class to get the address from latlng:

```
class FetchAddressWorker(
context: Context,
workerParameters: WorkerParameters
) :
Worker(context, workerParameters) {

companion object {
    const val TAG = "FetchAddressWorker"
}

override fun doWork(): Result {

    val geoCoder = Geocoder(applicationContext, Locale.getDefault())

    var errorMessage = ""

    val lat: Double = inputData.getDouble(CPKConstants.LATITUDE, 0.0)
    val lng: Double = inputData.getDouble(CPKConstants.LONGITUDE, 0.0)

    var addresses: List<Address> = emptyList()

    try {
        addresses =
            geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1)
    } catch (ioException: IOException) {
        // Catch network or other I/O problems.
        errorMessage = "Service not available"
        LogUtils.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException)
    } catch (illegalArgumentException: IllegalArgumentException) {
        // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
        errorMessage = "Invalid lat lng used"
        LogUtils.e(
            TAG,
            "$errorMessage. Latitude = $lat , Longitude =  $lng",
            illegalArgumentException
        )
    }

    // Handle case where no address was found.
    if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
        if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
            errorMessage = "No Address Found"
            LogUtils.e(TAG, errorMessage)
        }

        val data = Data.Builder()
            .putString(
                CPKConstants.FAILURE_RESULT,
                errorMessage
            )
            .build()

        return Result.failure(data)
    } else {
        val address: Address = addresses[0]
        // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
        // join them, and send them to the thread.
        val addressFragments = with(address) {
            (0..maxAddressLineIndex).map { getAddressLine(it) }
        }
        LogUtils.i(TAG, "Address Found " + addressFragments.joinToString(separator = "\n"))
        
       
        val data = Data.Builder()
            .putString(
                CPKConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                addressFragments.joinToString(separator = "\n")
            )
            .build()
        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success(data)
    }

}

}
```

Than use AddressResultReceiver in your fragment or activity:

```
 internal inner class AddressResultReceiver(handler: Handler) : ResultReceiver(handler) {

    override fun onReceiveResult(resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle?) {

        // Display the address string
        // or an error message sent from the intent service.
        val addressOutput = resultData?.getString(AppConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY).orEmpty()
        //displayAddressOutput()
        // Show a toast message if an address was found.
        if (resultCode == AppConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
            Boast.showText(requireContext(), "Address found = $addressOutput")
            txtContinueWith.text = addressOutput
        }

    }
}
```

You will need to initialize this in fragment or activity where you will use the above receiver to get the address:

```
  private var resultReceiver = AddressResultReceiver(Handler())
```

These are some constants that you should use as it is.

```
//Location Constants
const val LOCATION_SERVICE = "LOCATION_SERVICE"
const val SUCCESS_RESULT = 0
const val FAILURE_RESULT = 1
const val PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.gms.location.sample.locationaddress"
const val RECEIVER = "$PACKAGE_NAME.RECEIVER"
const val RESULT_DATA_KEY = "${PACKAGE_NAME}.RESULT_DATA_KEY"
const val LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA = "${PACKAGE_NAME}.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA"
```

Start worker from view

```
  private fun startAddressWorkManager(location: Location) {

    val inputData = Data.Builder()
        .putDouble(CPKConstants.LATITUDE, location.latitude)
        .putDouble(CPKConstants.LONGITUDE, location.longitude)
        .build()

    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()

    val fetchAddressWorkRequest: WorkRequest =
        OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<FetchAddressWorker>()
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(inputData)
            .build()

    WorkManager
        .getInstance(this)
        .enqueue(fetchAddressWorkRequest)

    WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(fetchAddressWorkRequest.id)
        .observe(this,
            { workInfo ->
                when (workInfo.state) {
                    WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> {
                        if (workInfo.state.isFinished) {
                            val addressData =
                                workInfo.outputData.getString(CPKConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT)
                            Timber.d("AddressData %s", addressData)
                            _binding?.searchEdt?.setText(addressData)
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Timber.d("workInfo %s", workInfo)
                    }
                }
            })

}
```

Comment: A simple location request turned into this unholy ugliness... I really hope no one copies anything from this answer and perpetuate all the atrocities it contains. Not that the other answers were much better.. but this one was the ugliest, so I had to take action.

Comment: @Ace, :))) Maybe you are right, but this answer contains some good methods. I saw many solutions, and all of them contain bugs. Most examples even don't check GPS settings, don't check `addOnFailureListener`, don't check `addOnSuccessListener` (`location == null` or `locationAvailability?.isLocationAvailable == false`) and so on. `FusedLocationProviderClient` consists of pile of bugs.