# get the current location once in android

Tags: java, android

I want to get the current location once in android, so I searched in stackoverflow and I found this solution:
[get the current location fast and once in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657948/get-the-current-location-fast-and-once-in-android) Is exactly what I want.

I created the class SingleShotLocationProvider but I get the error  "java.lang.SecurityException: "fused" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission." from android studio.

I accept the tip from the android studio to add the permission check (code bellow), but I get the error SingleShotLocationProvider.this cannot be referenced from a static context in `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)`

How can I fix this problem?

```
public class SingleShotLocationProvider {

    public static interface LocationCallback {
        public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location);
    }


    public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //SingleShotLocationProvider.this cannot be referenced from a static context
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }
            }, null);
        } else {
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                    }

                    @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
                    @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
                    @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
                }, null);
            }
        }
    }


    // consider returning Location instead of this dummy wrapper class
    public static class GPSCoordinates {
        public float longitude = -1;
        public float latitude = -1;

        public GPSCoordinates(float theLatitude, float theLongitude) {
            longitude = theLongitude;
            latitude = theLatitude;
        }

        public GPSCoordinates(double theLatitude, double theLongitude) {
            longitude = (float) theLongitude;
            latitude = (float) theLatitude;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file too?  Do you have anything in that file to allow this permission?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones done!

Answer (score 1):

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

Update: 
Since your are not into an Activity, you check permission in this way:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(contex,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

and to manifest

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: thanks! But I receive the same error "java.lang.SecurityException: "fused" location provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission."

Comment: Did you replace `context` all over instead `this`?

Comment: I uldated my answer. My bad, sorry.

Comment: Updated again. If you are using Android 6 to test, need to request permissions, not just to check them. Look in settings if are granted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133202/discussion-between-volt-and-florescu-george-ctlin).

Comment: don't change anything I receive the same error :/ @Florescu George Cătălin