# Update to androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha08: registerForActivityResult not allowed after onCreate anymore. How to use after onCreate?

Tags: android-fragments, permissions, androidx, registerforactivityresult

## Initial Question (18/05/2020):

So with the latest Update from

- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-**alpha07**

to

- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-**alpha08**

I get the error:

> FragmentXY is attempting to registerForActivityResult after being created. Fragments must call registerForActivityResult() before they are created (i.e. initialization, onAttach(), or onCreate()).

I used to check permissions in my StartFragment (Single Activity App, in onViewCreated) after showing to the User information about the use of those permissions and why they are needed. Everything worked perfectly for the last 3(?) months.

I see in the [changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha08):

> #### Behavior Changes
>
> [...]
> Calling registerForActivityResult() after onCreate() now throws an exception indicating that this is not allowed rather than silently failing to deliver results after a configuration change. (b/162255449)
> "

I downgraded back to version 1.3.0-alpha07 for the moment.
But if I need **registerForActivityResult** in my Fragments **AFTER**  the view is created (e.g. for permissions), how can I do it when upgrading to version 1.3.0-alpha08?

The docs state that I should use launch() in onCreate of my Fragment (see below) but that would mean I have to do it before the view is created, and that would be contradictory to my app flow.

> #### Behavior Changes
>
> [...]
> You can now call launch() on an ActivityResultLauncher in the onCreate() lifecycle method of a fragment. (b/161464278)
> "

As this behaviour seems to be intended by the developers, it is not a bug or anything but how can I continue using ActivityResults after onCreate? Any ideas?

---

## Edit (19/05/2020):

Thanks to @A.Andriyishyna I understand that registration (in onCreate) and execution (when needed, e.g. in onViewCreated) have to be handled separately.
Problem is that I have handy inline functions (with courtesy to [Flywith24](https://github.com/Flywith24/Flywith24-ActivityResultRequest/tree/15bfacf6a7d02e0467d7c0edd3813c83c5dd98f4)) in other files, which help me to separate the permission BL from the View (Fragment).
Is there a way to keep those inline functions without having to change them drastically?

1. Fragment

```
class GalleryFragment: ScopedFragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initializePermissions(requiredContext)
    }

    private fun initializePermissions(context: Context) {
        storagePermissions(
            context = context,
            actionOnGranted = { showImages() },
            actionOnDeclined = { showNoAccess() },
            actionRepeat = { initializePermissions(context) }
        )
    }
}
```

2. PermissionDSL

```
inline fun Fragment.storagePermissions(
    context: Context,
    crossinline actionOnGranted: () -> Unit,
    crossinline actionOnDeclined: () -> Unit,
    crossinline actionRepeat: () -> Unit
) {
    when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> {

            if (
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                actionOnGranted()
            } else {
                permission(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ) {
                    granted = {
                        actionOnGranted()
                    }
                    denied = {
                        actionRepeat()
                    }
                    explained = {
                        actionOnDeclined()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> {
            if (
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("Storage Permission", "Permission already granted.")
                actionOnGranted()
            } else {
                Log.d("Storage Permission", "No Permission Yet -> Ask for it!")
                permissions(
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION
                ) {
                    allGranted = {
                        actionOnGranted()
                    }
                    denied = {
                        Log.d("Storage Permission", "Denied")
                        actionRepeat()
                    }
                    explained = {
                        Log.d("Storage Permission", "Permanently Denied")
                        actionOnDeclined()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. PermissionExtension

```
inline fun Fragment.requestPermission(
    permission: String,
    crossinline granted: (permission: String) -> Unit = {},
    crossinline denied: (permission: String) -> Unit = {},
    crossinline explained: (permission: String) -> Unit = {}

) {
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { result ->
        when {
            result -> granted.invoke(permission)
            shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission) -> denied.invoke(permission)
            else -> explained.invoke(permission)
        }
    }.launch(permission)
}


inline fun Fragment.requestMultiplePermissions(
    vararg permissions: String,
    crossinline allGranted: () -> Unit = {},
    crossinline denied: (List<String>) -> Unit = {},
    crossinline explained: (List<String>) -> Unit = {}
) {
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { result: MutableMap<String, Boolean> ->

        val deniedList = result.filter { !it.value }.map { it.key }
        when {
            deniedList.isNotEmpty() -> {

                val map = deniedList.groupBy { permission ->
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) DENIED else EXPLAINED
                }

                map[DENIED]?.let { denied.invoke(it) }

                map[EXPLAINED]?.let { explained.invoke(it) }
            }
            else -> allGranted.invoke()
        }
    }.launch(permissions)
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It just means that you shouldn't *register* the callback after onCreate().

So you can do this

```
private val checkPermission = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
        ...
    }
```

and then *launch* the check anytime you need it

```
checkPermission.launch(array-of-permissions)
```

---

The [reason](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=ru#register):

> When starting an activity for a result, it is possible (and, in cases of memory-intensive operations such as camera usage, almost certain) that your process and your activity will be destroyed due to low memory.

> For this reason, the Activity Result APIs decouple the result callback from the place in your code where you launch the other activity. As the result callback needs to be available when your process and activity are recreated, the callback must be unconditionally registered every time your activity is created, even if the logic of launching the other activity only happens based on user input or other business logic.

Comment: Thanks for that clear explanation.
Problem is now that I'm not sure if I can keep my inline functions where the activityresults are handled.
I updated my initial question, maybe you have an idea?

Comment: I need to use them as inline functions inside ViewModel. Did you find any solution ? @goldensoju

Comment: @okarakose No I had no luck with inline functions. Actually I removed them all and have the logic now in fragment/viewmodel.

Comment: I found that instaed of using the fragment's context, using AppCompatActivity context avoided this problem.

((AppCompatActivity)context).registerForActivityResult

Comment: I didn't understand this answer until I realised that declaring a `val` in a fragment/activity will make it initialise in `onCreate`, thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

I had recently run into the same problem and I created my own PermissionDSL based on the Question here which helps me separate the permission code from fragments,
(Although this method is not very different from the original way of requesting permissions)

**Note** : This is the answer to the updated Question

> *... Is there a way to keep those inline functions without having to change them drastically?*

- This can be used only in fragments
- This is for requesting single permission although it can easily be extended for multiple permissions

**Step 1**
*Add gradle dependency*

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.3.0"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

**Step 2** *Add the following code*

```
inline fun <reified R : ActivityResultLauncher<String>> Fragment.requestPermission(
    permission: String,
    noinline granted: (permission: String) -> Unit = {},
    noinline denied: (permission: String) -> Unit = {},
    noinline explained: (permission: String) -> Unit = {}

): ReadOnlyProperty<Fragment, R> = PermissionResultDelegate(this, permission, granted, denied, explained)



class PermissionResultDelegate<R : ActivityResultLauncher<String>>(
    private val fragment: Fragment, private val permission: String,
    private val granted: (permission: String) -> Unit,
    private val denied: (permission: String) -> Unit,
    private val explained: (permission: String) -> Unit
) :
    ReadOnlyProperty<Fragment, R> {

    private var permissionResult: ActivityResultLauncher<String>? = null


    init {
        fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                fragment.apply {
                    permissionResult = registerForActivityResult(
                        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
                    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->

                        when {
                            isGranted -> granted(permission)
                            shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission) -> denied(permission)
                            else -> explained(permission)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                permissionResult = null
            }
        })
    }

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>): R {
        permissionResult?.let { return (it as R) }

        error("Failed to Initialize Permission")
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class DemoFrag : Fragment {

private val readStoragePermissionResult: ActivityResultLauncher<String> by requestPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            granted = {
                Log.d(TAG, "Granted")
            }, denied = {
        Log.d(TAG", "Denied")
    })

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        readStoragePermissionResult.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    }
}
```