# Fragments must call register registerForActivityResult() before they are created

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, fragment, registerforactivityresult

I am working on shopping app, i created a fragment for adding products to productslist. I need to get read external storage permission for adding photo to product so I am trying to use registerForActivityResult() in my fragment and i am getting this error. I am new to android programming so i dont know that i am using it right way.

I tried every answer from another questions but they didnt work too. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks for your help.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment AddActivity after being created. Fragments must call rHgS5orgPvsuzJ7shn8vw28y1XaePY4uDP() before they are created (i.e. initialization, onAttach(), or onCreate()).
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.prepareCallInternal(Fragment.java:3482)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.rHgS5orgPvsuzJ7shn8vw28y1XaePY4uDP(Fragment.java:3449)
        at com.example.TheDentalSupplies.AddActivity.showImageChooser(AddActivity.kt:120)
        at com.example.TheDentalSupplies.AddActivity.requestPermission(AddActivity.kt:96)
        at com.example.TheDentalSupplies.AddActivity.onViewCreated$lambda-1(AddActivity.kt:66)
        at com.example.TheDentalSupplies.AddActivity.lambda$gx8TAUa5Jk3WDkvGOWG0oB39kiM(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.TheDentalSupplies.-$$Lambda$AddActivity$gx8TAUa5Jk3WDkvGOWG0oB39kiM.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
```

AddActivity.kt:

```
class AddActivity : Fragment() {
private lateinit var img:ImageView
private lateinit var requestLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<String>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        requestLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) {
            if(it){
                    showImageChooser(img)
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "PERM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.addpost, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val image1 = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.addImage1)
        val image2 = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.addImage2)
        val image3 = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.addImage3)
        val image4 = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.addImage4)
        val image5 = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.addImage5)

        image1.setOnClickListener {
            requestPermission(image1)
            }
        image2.setOnClickListener {
            requestPermission(image2)
        }
        image3.setOnClickListener {
            requestPermission(image3)
        }
        image4.setOnClickListener {
            requestPermission(image4)
        }
        image5.setOnClickListener {
            requestPermission(image5)
        }
        val publishBtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.addPublishBtn)

        publishBtn.setOnClickListener { addItem(view) }

    }


    private fun requestPermission(imageView: ImageView) {
            img = imageView

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                showImageChooser(imageView)
            }
            else{

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), Constants.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
                requestLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)


            }


    }


    fun showImageChooser(imageView: ImageView) {
        val galleryIntent = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        )

        val launchSomeActivity = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val data: Intent? = result.data
                if (data != null){
                    try {
                        val mSelectedImageFileUri = data.data!!

                        //setUserPic.setImageURI(Uri.parse(selectedImageFileUri.toString()))
                        GlideLoader(requireContext()).loadUserPicture(mSelectedImageFileUri,imageView)

                        //FireStoreClass().uploadImgCloud(requireActivity(), mSelectedImageFileUri)


                    }catch (e: IOException){
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "Image selection failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        launchSomeActivity.launch(galleryIntent)
    }

    private fun addItem(view: View) {
        //val image1 = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.addImage1)
        val addProductName = view.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.addTitleEditText).text.toString()
        val addProductDesc = view.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.addDescEditText).text.toString()
        val addProductPrice = view.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.addPrice).text.toString()
        val addProductCat = view.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.selectCategoryEt).text.toString()

        when{
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addProductName.trim { it <= ' ' }) -> Toast.makeText(activity,
                "Please Enter Product Name.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            TextUtils.isEmpty(addProductDesc.trim { it <= ' ' }) -> Toast.makeText(activity,
                "Please Enter Product Description.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            TextUtils.isEmpty(addProductCat.trim { it <= ' ' }) -> Toast.makeText(activity,
                "Please Select Product Category.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            TextUtils.isEmpty(addProductPrice.trim { it <= ' ' }) -> Toast.makeText(activity,
                "Please Enter Product Price.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            else -> {
                //val index = 0
                val firebaseUser: String = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
                val product = ProductItem(R.drawable.add_box,
                    addProductName,
                    0.0,
                    "Serhat Yilmaz",
                    addProductPrice.toInt(),
                    addProductDesc,
                    addProductCat.toInt(),
                    firebaseUser)

                //Datasource.productList.add(index,product)
                FireStoreClass().addProduct(requireActivity(), product)
                //Toast.makeText(activity, "Product Published!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val action = AddActivityDirections.actionAddPostNavActivityToProductFragment()
                view.findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update to androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha08: registerForActivityResult not allowed after onCreate anymore. How to use after onCreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879320/update-to-androidx-fragmentfragment1-3-0-alpha08-registerforactivityresult-no)

Comment: Did you read the [Activity Result documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)? It explains exactly how to use the API.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I manage to fix it by cut and paste the launchSomeActivity to the bottom of onViewCreated function

Answer (score 1):

I manage to fix it by cutting and pasting the launchSomeActivity to the bottom of onViewCreated function.

Comment: Hi, i have a very similar situation, how did you setImageUri to the imageview  if you move launchSomeActivity to onviewCreated(). thanks